# Unable to read rows from MySQL due to InvalidOperationException

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So basically this is my code, Visual Studio gives me the following error message: "An unhandled exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" occurred in System Data" and it points to the line .Fill(Table).
Details: "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized" "

Edit: ListViewSale is the ListViewBox I would like the MySQL data to be pasted in.

If anyone could give me some input as to what is wrong, I would really appreciate it. The mysql login information is handled with earlier in the code with the following code:

```
  Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(INFORMATION HERE)       

  Public Sub updateList()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Produkt"
        Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim Table As New DataTable
        Dim i As Integer

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = connection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(Table)
    End With

    For i = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListViewSale
            .Items.Add(Table.Rows(i)("id"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("Name"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("Price"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("Quantity"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("Description"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Click `View Details` to...well, get more details

Comment: Have already checked that the information exists in the database.

Comment: Read the exception message on the exception - and let us have it...

Comment: I'll just bet that the exception says that the connection isn't open.

Comment: "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized"

Comment: You need to have connection.Open before you execute the command. In your case, before the SqlAdapter.Fill

Comment: When I edited in connection.Open(), Visual Studio returned: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Comment: Now, hold the mouse over the objects in that line and see which one is `Nothing`.  I'll bet Option Strict is off too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways do what you want more economically:

```vb
Private dtProduct As DataTable

Public Sub updateList()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT a,b,c,q,e ... FROM Produkt"

    Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(mySQLConnStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbcon)

            dtProduct = New DataTable() 
            dbcon.Open()
            dtProduct.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

        End Using
    End Using
    ...
```

1. **Dont use a global connection** object.  Create it, use it and dispose of it

   - You can however, use a global connection string so it is not littered all over your code
2. **Use `Using` blocks to close and dispose of things** which have a `.Dispose` method.  This allows them to release resources they allocate.
3. Rather than setting the SQL and connection as properties for the Command object, this passes them as constructor args.  This is just personal preference, but once you get into the habit of it, it makes the code more concise and less likely that you will forget those key items.
4. If you specify the columns in your SQL you can control the order they appear.
5. There is no need for a `DataAdapter` just to fill a table.  The code above uses a `DataReader` to do so.

If you do use a `DataAdpater`, make it global and configure it fully.  This will prevent you from having to run that code again.  `daProduct.Fill(dtProduct)` will (can) **refresh** the contents, getting just any new or changed data.

Finally, the `ListView` is very ill suited for db operations.  First, everything is stored as string.  That means numerics like Price and Quantity have to be converted back for use (or updates).  Second, using a `DataGridView`, all that code to populate the LV can be replaced by:

```vb
dgvProd.DataSource = dtProduct
```

The DGV will create and columns, and add all the rows with no need to loop or create each row.  The data remains in the `DataTable` and Typed.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! However, I got the same error on this line: "            dtProduct.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)" - ErrorMessage: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Comment: Thanks! Would I still use the same For Each-loop to print it to the ListViewBox? I will also try to use a DataGridView to see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: that one line will build it and fill it.  they are very very easy to use with basic behavior /look but have lots of properties and events so you can do anything you want.  The ListView stores everything as string and isnt bound - it is just horrible to db things